# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Exception::getClass() in /home/tree21/public_html/system/engine/front.php on line 65

Tags: php, opencart

**Fatal error**: Call to undefined method Exception::**getClass()**

Comment: And what do you expect?

Comment: Obviously Exception doesn't have a getClass method.

Answer (score 0):

Simply! You are calling a function which is not available

Comment: I define function  but problem is still.

Comment: You should elaborate it more by providing snippet of code

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's OpenCart error. It might be seen after new extension is added or after OC version update as they recently changed some file paths.

The URL probably looks like:

```
http://example.com/index.php?route=exampleA/exampleB/exampleC
```

You need to correct the route. Start adding extension in front. It works in some cases.

The updated URL would be:

```
http://example.com/index.php?route=extension/exampleA/exampleB/exampleC
```

If that works fine, you need to correct path in your extension source. If not keep searching in documentation.

If you work with cart.php it was moved from `system/library/cart.php` to `system/library/cart/cart.php` together with some other files. Good luck and try to give us more details in the future.